# Bottom fragment not displayed when a fragment using RelativeLayout is added on top

Tags: android

I am pretty new to Android development, and I am having some trouble with fragments. I have one activity, and the activity's layout has two `FrameLayout`'s, one on top and one on bottom, that serve as containers for two fragments that I want to add. The fragment that I want to add on top is a `CalculatorFragment`, and the one I want to add on the bottom is an `AdvFragment`. The `CalculatorFragment` uses a `RelativeLayout`; the `AdvFragment` uses a `FrameLayout`.

Whenever I add the `CalculatorFragment` on top and the `AdvFragment` on the bottom in my code, when I run it, only the `CalculatorFragment` shows up on top; the `AdvFragment` doesn't show up on the bottom. But, if I switch them and add the `AdvFragment` on top and the `CalculatorFragment` on the bottom in my code, both of them will show up correctly positioned upon execution. If I only add the `AdvFragment` on the bottom and don't add the `CalculatorFragment` on the top in my code, the `AdvFragment` will show up correctly positioned when the program is run. Thus, whenever the `CalculatorFragment` is added on top, no fragment ends up showing below it even though the fragment was added in the code. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Here is the relevant code:

MainActivity.java (in the onCreate() method):

```
//Adding calcfragment on top and advfragment on bottom
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

CalculatorFragment calcfragment = new CalculatorFragment();
AdvFragment advFragment = new AdvFragment();


f_manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

FragmentTransaction f_transaction = f_manager.beginTransaction();

f_transaction.add(R.id.main_frame, calcfragment);
f_transaction.add(R.id.advanced_frame, advFragment);


f_transaction.commit();
```

MainActivity's xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.rm1399.myfirstapplication.MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/highlighted_text_material_light"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id = "@+id/main_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
       >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id = "@+id/advanced_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

CalculatorFragment's xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context="com.example.rm1399.myfirstapplication.MainActivity"
                android:background="@color/highlighted_text_material_light"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/calculate"
        android:text="Calculate"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:id="@+id/button0"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/result"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button0"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button0"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button3"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="4"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/calculate"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/calculate"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="6"
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button4"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="7"
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button5"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="8"
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button6"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="9"
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button7"/>

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+"
        android:id="@+id/plus"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/multiply"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/multiply"/>

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:id="@+id/minus"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/plus"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/multiply"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/multiply"/>

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="*"
        android:id="@+id/multiply"
        android:layout_below="@+id/plus"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"/>

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="/"
        android:id="@+id/divide"
        android:layout_below="@+id/minus"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/multiply"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/multiply"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="700dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:hint = "Result"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button1"/>

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/divide"
        android:layout_toLeftOf= "@+id/divide"
        android:id="@+id/openparentheses"
        android:text = "("

        />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/openparentheses"
        android:layout_below="@id/divide"
        android:text=")"
        android:id="@+id/closeparentheses"
        />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Clear"
        android:id="@+id/clear"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Advanced"
        android:id="@+id/openadv"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/calculate"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id = "@+id/advanced_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

AdvFragment's XML Layout (it just says "Advanced Fragment"):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context="com.example.rm1399.myfirstapplication.AdvFragment"
             android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="415dp"
        android:textSize="100px"
        android:text="Advanced Fragment"
        android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
        android:autoText="false"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

In both CalculatorFragment.java and AdvFragment.java, I am using inflater.inflate() to return the appropriate layouts.

[Upon execution, I am seeing this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5Gms.png)

As you can see, even though I added the AdvFragment in my code below the CalculatorFragment, it's not showing up upon execution. So again, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In mainactivity's xml, write below line in linearlayout

```
 android:weightSum="3"
```

and then check if it helps you or not.

Comment: No, unfortunately this doesn't help. I don't think the weights are the problem though, because when I go onto design mode in my original mainactivity's xml, I can see the two framelayouts where the fragments should be placed.

Comment: Bind your Linearlayout in ScrollView,it might help.

Comment: No, still doesn't work. However, I don't want to have a scrolling feature in the app. I just want two fragments to show up, one on top and one on bottom, when the app opens.